# Explore containing folder instead of open containing folder

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, windows-explorer

I use Visual Studio to do a lot of my coding. I find the open containing folder feature quite helpful. But I don't want the folder to be "opened" by the windows explorer, instead I want to "explore" the folder -- you know, get the nice little frame showing me all the other folders on the left hand side. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you,
Rohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking ShellExecute(), use the explore verb instead of the open verb: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx.

Edit: If you don't mean programmatically, open Windows Explorer, go to Tools -> Folder Options, select the File Types tab, locate the Folder entry in the list (not File Folder!), click Advanced, and set "explore" as default instead of "open".

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much difference anymore between 'explore' and 'open' if you're talking about a folder.  They both open the same window, just with different options active.  When you 'open' the folder, you're only one click away (on my system at least) from seeing the folder tree as well- just click the "Folders" button in the toolbar.